Speed Up Git Subtree Push for a Large Codebase Sharing Common Logic
We use Git subtree to manage a large shared codebase between multiple services. The subtree contains common logics and helpers. We are experiencing a significant delay of up to 25 minutes to push to the shared repository.
I have tried subtree split and rejoin and it is not reducing the time taken to push to the subtree.

Are there any best practices or optimizations that can help reduce the delay when pushing a subtree in a large shared codebase?
Would an alternative strategy (e.g., Git submodules, or restructuring the repository) be more efficient for managing shared logic between services?


git subtree push runsgit subtree split; my guess on a big codebase split is slow. In that case switching to submodules should help — submodules don't require constant rebuilding. They surely have their own quirks.
